# Trying to message new connections to Discord Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so first of all, I am pretty new to Python and Bot programming.
What I am trying to achieve is, to send a private message to everyone that has newly connected to my discord server. I have looked through the API documentation but was unable to find anything that checks for new connections. I thought about continuously checking the user list and comparing it to itself until it finds a new entry. But that seems unnecessarily hard. Any ideas or functions I overlooked that could be useful for this scenario?

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random

client = discord.Client()

def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = json_data[0]["q"] + "\n-" + json_data[0]["a"]
    return (quote)

bad_words = ['list of bad words']

zuegelungen = [
  "Also hömma, sowat will ich hier net lesen!",
  "ich glaub ich seh net richtig, was ist das den für ne Ausdrucksweise",
  "Ja lecko mio, wat lief den in deiner Erziehung falsch, sowat sacht man doch nicht."
]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Eingeloggt als {0.user}".format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if "inspirieren" in message.content.lower():
        quote = get_quote()
        await message.channel.send(quote)

    if "louis" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Habe ich da Louis gehört?\nDas ist schon nen geiler Typ...")

    if "koks" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("MIT NUTTEN!")

    if ".cookie" in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(":cookie:")

    for word in bad_words:
        if word in message.content.lower():
          await message.channel.send(random.choice(zuegelungen))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Danke fürs beitreten auf den offiziellen DBG-Discord-Server.\nKönntest du mir bitte deinen echten Vornamen senden?")


client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

This is the code of the whole bot. I know some of it is done ineffective etc. its mainly for practicing and having some fun.

Comment: By "newly connected" you mean when someone joins?

Comment: Yes I do, that was the wording I was searching for ^^

Answer (score 0):

if what you mean is to send a private message to an user when it joins the server (new user joins server) then this should work:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)    
token = "Your Token Goes Here"

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    msg = "Your Message goes here"
    await member.send(msg)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Its also worth mentioning the intents, as this code won't work without them

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for the help. And yes I meant to send a PM to a user who joins the server. I tried out your code but it appears to not be working. The other functions of the bot which I used to try it on are working, however, when joining the server I do not get the message which I wrote.

Comment: It will fail if you have different names for the client, or if you are declaring everything inside a class. This piece of code works, but if it isn't working for you then do you mind sharing how your code looks like?

Comment: yes, sorry for not having done that earlier. I added it to my Original post.

Comment: Just like @ŁukaszKwieciński said, it needs intents to work. I edited the answer so you can see what needs to be change